# Group DataFrame by column, perform operation on members, and output results in new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have some `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple'],
                   'subtype':['Fuji', 'Cortland', 'Ambrosia'],
              'score':[1,5,10], 
              'distance':[25,50,75]})
```

I would like to group this DataFrame by `type`, calculate the `distance` ratios for all members (e.g. 25/50, 25/75, 50/75), and return the output of this operation in a new DataFrame, such as:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need cross join by `type` first, then remove rows with same value of `subtypes` by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last create ratio column with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and division with [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df = df.merge(df, on='type')
df = (df[df['subtype_x'].ne(df['subtype_y'])]
              .assign(ratio=df['distance_x'].div(df['distance_y'])))
print (df)

    type subtype_x  score_x  distance_x subtype_y  score_y  distance_y  \
1  Apple      Fuji        1          25  Cortland        5          50   
2  Apple      Fuji        1          25  Ambrosia       10          75   
3  Apple  Cortland        5          50      Fuji        1          25   
5  Apple  Cortland        5          50  Ambrosia       10          75   
6  Apple  Ambrosia       10          75      Fuji        1          25   
7  Apple  Ambrosia       10          75  Cortland        5          50   

      ratio  
1  0.500000  
2  0.333333  
3  2.000000  
5  0.666667  
6  3.000000  
7  1.500000
```

Also if need remove distance columns you can assign new column with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and remove distance columns:

```
df = df.merge(df, on='type', suffixes=('1','2'))
df = df[df['subtype1'].ne(df['subtype2'])].copy()
df['ratio'] = df.pop('distance1').div(df.pop('distance2'))
print (df)
    type  subtype1  score1  subtype2  score2     ratio
1  Apple      Fuji       1  Cortland       5  0.500000
2  Apple      Fuji       1  Ambrosia      10  0.333333
3  Apple  Cortland       5      Fuji       1  2.000000
5  Apple  Cortland       5  Ambrosia      10  0.666667
6  Apple  Ambrosia      10      Fuji       1  3.000000
7  Apple  Ambrosia      10  Cortland       5  1.500000
```

Comment: Do you mind adding to your excellent answer a bit about the `.ne` and `.assign` methods?

Comment: @ConfusedDolphin - sure, give me a sec.

Comment: Brilliant explanation; you just introduced me to methods I didn't know existed. Thank you for sharing your knowledge freely.

Comment: Any advantage of `df.assign(ratio=df['distance_x'].div(df['distance_y']))` versus 
`df['ratio2'] = df['distance_x'].div(df['distance_y'])`? I guess the advantage of the former is that your can use it in combination with other methods?

Comment: @ConfusedDolphin - exactly you are right, it was created for method chaining (in another words one line solutions)